# Ansible job output to json file, while keeping default stdout

Tags: ansible

I need to run ansible-playbook and output the run results to a json file, and **also** keep the normal stdout log.

In other words, keep the human readable log stream on stdout, but create a machine readable output to a file.

---

I can get ansible-playbook to output a json log by setting

```
[defaults]
log_path = /tmp/log.txt
stdout_callback = json
```

The problem is that this is overriding the stdout settings, so it doesn't output the "normal" job output text to stdout anymore.
Instead it dumps the json text after the run completes and also outputs the json to stdout.

What I'm looking for would be some sort of `log_callback = json` or `log_callback = yaml` type setting, and leaving `stdout_callback` default. However, nothing seems fit that while reviewing the available options.

Comment: All 3 of those are plugins, so if you don't like the way they behave, you can copy them into your ansible plugins directory and make one that behaves as you wish

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks. So, are you saying that my requirements can't be done without making a custom plugin? Also, all 3 of what are plugins?

Comment: I believe that's true, since my experience with the json callback matches yours, and [it doesn't seem to have many configuration knobs](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/blob/1.3.0/plugins/callback/json.py#L9-L32). The 3 callbacks you mentioned: `json`, `yaml`, and the normal one `default`. If you haven't seen it yet, [ara](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara#readme) is also very handy for structured playbook capture

Comment: Ok thanks. Seems so involved either way. I would think needing machine readable output from ansible for various automation would be a common thing and built into ansible core features but I guess I was wrong there :/

Comment: It may very well be, but just isn't to your liking. But if you're trying to automate ansible, what you're describing sounds more like [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner#readme) or AWX versus trying to `expect`-ify ansible-playbook

Comment: @mdaniel ansible-runner is exactly what I was looking for! If you form that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated interaction with ansible has a dedicated library, [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner#readme)